# I've checked everything in my YAML file and yet it gives me an error

Tags: java, yaml, spigot

I'm writing a spigot plugin and in the config.yml, I get an error, this is the error:

```
 Caused by: org.yaml.snakeyaml.scanner.ScannerExcption: mapping values are not allowed here
    in string, line 3, column 16:
     MaintenanceMode: "false"
                    ^
```

This is the YAML file:

```
// Maintenance Mode

MaintenanceMode: "false"

// Prefix

Prefix: "&7[&eMaintenanceSystem&7]"

// The message displayed when a player joins the server while its under Maintenance

MaintenanceMessage: "&4ExampleMC | &eMaintenance"

// UUID of the players that can join the server while its under Maintenance

AllowedPlayers:
  - ""
```

Can anyone tell me what's causing the error and how to fix it? I've tried everything I knew I could do

Answer (score 1):

Comments in YAML should start with #
See: [YAML - Comments](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/yaml/yaml_comments.htm)

```
# Maintenance Mode
MaintenanceMode: "false"

# Prefix
Prefix: "&7[&eMaintenanceSystem&7]"

# The message displayed when a player joins the server while its under Maintenance
MaintenanceMessage: "&4ExampleMC | &eMaintenance"

# UUID of the players that can join the server while its under Maintenance
AllowedPlayers:
  - ""
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first line should be exactly this:

```
---
```

"The file starts with three dashes. These dashes indicate the start of a new YAML document." -- [source](https://www.cloudbees.com/blog/yaml-tutorial-everything-you-need-get-started)

Comment: It still doesn't work

Comment: When you added a first line with just three dashes in it, what did the error message change to?